# where do we use the methods __str__ and __repr__ in python3?

Tags: python-3.4

Can any one explain **repr** and **str** methods in python where do we use them in practical examples? I understand that **str** and **repr** returns the string representation of an object. But why would we need them?

Comment: yes, but i didn't understand the concept clearly with the answers

Comment: If there is something you don't understand in the dozens of obvious Google hits, including at least half a dozen on Stack Overflow, please ask a specific question about that detail, instead if posting yet another duplicate. Otherwise, how would you be able to understand the answers to your own question?